# Error acceso Oracle Publisher 12c

Tags: error500, oracle-19c

Tengo un problema al intentar acceder a las URL de una instalación de Oracle Publisher 12c.

- La Base de datos es una `19C`.
- El Weblogic es la versión `12.2.1.3.0`.
- La versión de Publisher es `12.2.1.3.0`.
- El usuario con el que intento acceder es el mismo creado en la
  instalación del Publisher (weblogic)
- Todos los servicios están arriba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si accedo a las URLs `http://DESKTOP-10B4UTL:9600/console` o `http://DESKTOP-10B4UTL:9600/em` sin problemas.

Pero si lo intento con `http://DESKTOP-10B4UTL:9602/xmlpserver` o `http://DESKTOP-10B4UTL:9602/analytics` me da el error:

```bash
"Error 500--Internal Server Error
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request."
```

He estado mirando otras opciones en este mismo portal y otras soluciones pero ninguna ha funcionado.
El fichero de log (bipublisher.log) pone esto en la última ejecución...nada parecido a otras cosas que he encontrado por la Web.

```
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.446+01:00] [bi_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Global context initialized
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.446+01:00] [bi_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Marking BIP Ready
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.451+01:00] [bi_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Initializing oracle.xdo.servlet.resources.action.ActionServlet
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.451+01:00] [bi_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Initializing oracle.xdo.servlet.monitor.audit.AuditServlet
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.451+01:00] [bi_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Initializing oracle.xdo.jmx.XDOMBeanManagerServlet
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.470+01:00] [bi_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] MBean EMDomain:Name=bipublisher#11.1.1,Location=bi_server1,Type=EMIntegration,EMTargetType=oracle_bi_publisher,Application=bipublisher,ApplicationVersion=11.1.1 is already registered
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.470+01:00] [bi_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Initializing oracle.xdo.enterpriseScheduler.scheduler.servlet.ConfigCheckServlet
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.478+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  ===== ConfigCheckServlet :: Start Scheduler...
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.508+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Read jms_cluster_config using ConfigProvider: /Scheduler/jms_cluster_config.properties
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.510+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] JMSContext initialized. SharedFolder:null, JobRecoveryEnabled:true, JobRecoveryLimit:1, InstanceStatusInterval:15000, InstanceStatusExpire:30000, InstanceStatusCheck:1000, ScheduleDataChunkBytes:10485760
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.596+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  ===== JMSAdminWrapper :: JMSAdminWrapper is to start JMSWrapper on instance: bip.bi_server1, ID: bip.bi_server1
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.805+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  ===== JMSAdminWrapper :: JMSAdminWrapper successfully started JMSWrapper.
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.805+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  ===== ClusterAdminWrapper :: ClusterAdminWrapper is to start.
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.807+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  ===== ClusterAdminWrapper :: ClusterAdminWrapper successfully started.
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.807+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  ===== QuartzService :: QuartzService is to start Quartz.
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.917+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  ===== QuartzService :: QuartzService successfully started Quartz.
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.917+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  ===== ClusterAdminWrapper.resendJMSMessagesUsingCPStore :: Dumping entire Checkpoint Store, number of entries=0  instanceID=bip.bi_server1
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.917+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]  ===== ConfigCheckServlet :: Scheduler started successfully.
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.917+01:00] [bi_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Initializing oracle.xdo.servlet.ui.scheduler.SchedulerServlet
[2022-11-13T15:39:56.925+01:00] [bi_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 267] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-0000000a,0:2505] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Initializing oracle.xdo.servlet.ui.schedule.ScheduleServlet
[2022-11-13T15:41:59.361+01:00] [bi_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 188] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 3ec9feb1-0ee1-4f78-b95f-096a136feadc-00000104,0] [APP: bipublisher] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] [SI-Key: ssi] BI SSO Enabled=true
```

Gracias
Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Si se desactiva la opción en el Enterprise Manager Single Sign-On (SSO) el error que se produce es más indicativo, pero sigue dando error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es una respuesta a que?

Comment: Hola. Por desgracia no. Lo he añadido porque tengo el mismo error pero el mensaje es distinto. Supongo que te ha molestado que haya usado la opción de respuesta. Si es así te pido disculpas.

Comment: A mi no me molesto, pero el sitio tiene un orden para las cosas. No es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas... y la gente espera ver respuestas donde dice respuestas ;)